# Customizing the last child of a 2010 dropdown menu

Tags: 2010, editing-menu

Is there a simple way in CSS or XSLT to style the last child of a SharePoint 2010 single tier dropdown menu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuery to do that... using XSLT doesn't make sense at all

```
var option_last = $('#my_select option:last-child').val();
```

then change the style with

```
$(option_last).addClass("my class");
```

Comment: Isn't there a last child element in XSLT that can be used to apply a different style across a set of menus.

Comment: you could have a common js that does this job automatically everywhere